# How to get Page Views by C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm looking for a solution to get the recently page views by a SPListItem Object (in C#).

Is this possible? I don't want to use the search! There is a managedproperty called "RecentViews". But I can't access this property by C#.

Is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not want to use the search? It is the search that is responsible of analysing usage and hence update the `ViewsRecent` property on documents and files..

Comment: hmm.. because items arent instantly in the index... its up to 5 minutes with cont. crawl. And I didnt find a solution to push items directly to the index... I think, there is no solution for that :)

Comment: No there is not, but the properties holding views is updated by search (really by a specific timer job that processes search statistics, which by default runs once a day) so you will have no other way of getting this information anyways

Comment: uhm.. okay! thanks for that! Can you tell me, what the name of the timer job is?

Comment: @domsen123 if it is highly critical that you can't wait for 5 minutes for continuous crawl , you can try reducing the continuous crawl interval to 1 min .